# booting into a virtual machine from a linux installed on external hard drive

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, virtual-machine, external-hard-drive

I am running windows 8 and have a linux Ubuntu 12.04 installed on an external hard drive, can I install a virtual machine on windows and run the linux system installed on my external HD?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In the VM's settings, give it pass-through access to the USB device which represents your external HDD, and tell it to boot from USB. It should see it just like the host would.

Comment: Really? Even if the Linux install was made "normally" not on a VM? The hardware specs that Linux will be expecting will be different. Won't that cause problems?

Comment: Well, if it's expecting a different architecture, then yes. The kernel is fairly intelligent about recognising hardware differences - consider how many variations a liveCD install will encounter, and consider that Ubuntu in particular is set up to, as they put it, "Just Work".

Comment: Yeah, but I would guess things like the `fstab` will probably need some tweaking. Have you actually tried this successfully?

Comment: Well, it depends on the setup. Ubuntu uses uuids for filesystems now, so it shouldn't really matter, since that's stored on the drive too.

Comment: Also, no, not with an external HDD, but with a flash drive. USB access worked just fine.

Comment: Fair enough, +1 :)